# How to change cursor position in powershell console

Tags: powershell, console

I currently assign the current CursorPosition to a variable in Powershell so that I can overwrite the same space when performing a count down for example in a script, as below:

```
$errorPos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
for ($i=5; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $errorPos
    Write-Host -NoNewline -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Black "$i"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

What I'd like to do, it take the current position of the cursor and move it forward two spaces, then assign it to another variable.  I could just use:

```
write-host "  "
```

but I don't want to overwrite the text currently occupying that space.

I think it can be accomplished using X and Y coordinate but am not having much success.

Comment: Sounds like a progress bar with a countdown number for the status text to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to move the 'X' forward by 2 you can just do this after creating your `errorPos` variable:

```
$errorPos.X += 2
```

You can modify the variable directly by using `$errorPos.X` and `.Y`.

Comment: Great, thats solved it, thanks ConnorLSW.  I think I may have had something like this when I was playing around but the ISE doesn't like manipulating the position of the cursor so it seems!

Comment: definitely test this in the normal prompt, the ISE will be very unlikely to play nice :) - you may want to take a look at `Write-Progress` too which is the 'better' way to do what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer isn't working for me on PowerShell 5.1 or 7.4, I'm not sure if something changed with conhost.exe or if it really just never worked.

While editing the properties of `$Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition` doesn't work, assigning it a hashtable with `x` & `y` keys *does* work:

```
for ($i=5; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
  Write-Host -NoNewline -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Black "$i"
  $x, $y = $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition -split ','
  # Splitting the positions into $x & $y prevents this line from being very long:
  $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = @{  x = $x - 1  ;  y = $y  }
  Start-Sleep 1
}
```

**HOWEVER**, `$Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition` often doesn't function properly outside of the parent scope. You can use `[Console]::SetCursorPosition` instead; just make sure that the arguments you provide it are integers:

```
# This should cause the cursor to move diagonally to the lower right:
&{
  for ($i=0; $i -lt 3; $i++) {
    Start-Sleep 1
    $x, $y = $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition -split ',' -as 'int[]'
    [Console]::SetCursorPosition(  $x + 1  ,  $y + 1  )
  }
}
```

I don't really like mixing the use of `$Host.UI.RawUI` and `[Console]` together, though; so, here's an alternative version that utilizes `[Console]::GetCursorPosition()`:

```
# This should cause the cursor to move diagonally to the lower right:
&{
  for ($i=0; $i -lt 3; $i++) {
    Start-Sleep 1
    $x, $y = [Console]::GetCursorPosition() -split '\D' -ne '' -as 'int[]'
    [Console]::SetCursorPosition(  $x + 1  ,  $y + 1  )
  }
}
```